# "10th patient" is the answer to the question. I want to know as to how to ask a question to get this answer in English

Tags: grammar

Similarly, if the answer is 10th president, how do you ask a question in English to get this answer. I wanted to ask a doctor to find out how many Corona patients had been diagnosed. But, when he said that this is the 100th patient, I didn't know how to ask a question to get that answer.

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Do you want to ask *'how many patients have been admitted?'*?

Comment: Which president came after **the** 9th president? (*Note the correct use of the definite article.*)

Answer (score 0):

If the patient is the hundredth one to be admitted, (but you don't know that yet) you could ask "How many patients have been admitted before this one?" and would receive the answer "Ninety-nine", or you could ask "How many patients have been admitted including this one?" and receive the answer "A hundred/one hundred". You could just ask "How many patients have been admitted so far?". Likewise "How many presidents have there been [before or including] this one?"